# How can I ensure a dataframe has completed being written via pandas.to_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas, temporary-files

I have been creating a little script that queries a database and returns the result. I have then been using Pandas.to_csv() to write it out to a CSV tempfile before I upload that CSV result to a cloud location. The trouble I am running into is ensuring that the pandas.to_csv() function has completed writing the CSV tempfile before I upload it to the cloud location. The only way I have consistently ensured that that date makes it to the temp file before the upload is by keeping the

> print(temp.tell())

line of code in the example below. If I comment it out, no data gets uploaded.

Example code below:

```
def write_to_temporary_csv_file(df, file_name, token, folder_id):
   with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', suffix='.csv', delete=False) as temp:
       print("DataFrame: ", df)
       df.to_csv(temp, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
       print("temp.tell() size: ", temp.tell())
       print("File size: ", str(round((os.stat(temp.name).st_size/1024), 2)), "kb")
       new_file_path = tempfile.gettempdir() + '/' + customer_name + '_' + file_name + '_' +  current_date + '.csv'

       ## Check if newly created renamed temp file already exist, if it does remove it to create it
       remove_temporary_file(new_file_path)
       os.link(temp.name, new_file_path)
       upload_response = upload_file(token, folder_id, new_file_path)

       ## Remove both the temp file and the newly created renamed temp file
       remove_temporary_file(temp.name)
       remove_temporary_file(new_file_path)
```

Image 1 (with temp.tell() included:
[image: Image 1 (with temp.tell() included]
Image 2 (with temp.tell() commented out:
[image: Image 2 (with temp.tell() commented out]

Comment: So why wouldn't it finish writing?  There aren't many cases where `to_csv` would not finish and not raise an error right?  Maybe a full disk?  What else are you worried about that the code within pandas would return without it actually having completed writing the file?

Comment: is your with statement commented out on porpuse?

Comment: Main concern is that the df.to_csv() has returned with 0 data written as mentioned, if I remove that print(temp.tell()) I almost always get os.stat(temp.name).st_size returning 0 in size. Also, just checked my disk have enough space there so that isn't the problem. This is working towards an automated process where I would like the reliability of returning files with data to be as close to 100% as possible. Will update the example code with outputs here in a second

Comment: @Raphael, no it is not, fat fingered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be caused by the fact that you keep your file opened (as long as you are inside the with block). That might cause the content not being flushed to disk.

```
def write_to_temporary_csv_file(df, file_name, token, folder_id):
   with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', suffix='.csv', delete=False) as temp:
       print("DataFrame: ", df)
       df.to_csv(temp, index=False, encoding='utf-8')

   # at this point we can close the file by exiting the with block

   print("temp.tell() size: ", temp.tell())
   print("File size: ", str(round((os.stat(temp.name).st_size/1024), 2)), "kb")
   new_file_path = tempfile.gettempdir() + '/' + customer_name + '_' + file_name + '_' +  current_date + '.csv'

   ## Check if newly created renamed temp file already exist, if it does remove it to create it
   remove_temporary_file(new_file_path)
   os.link(temp.name, new_file_path)
   upload_response = upload_file(token, folder_id, new_file_path)

   ## Remove both the temp file and the newly created renamed temp file
   remove_temporary_file(temp.name)
   remove_temporary_file(new_file_path)
```

Comment: Well I'll be darned. Thank you!